# Show date on DatePickerDialog instead of "Set Date"

Tags: android, date, datepicker, fragment

Currently my DatePickerFragment is like this :

[image]

I want to make it

[image]

That is, to show the date in place of "Set Date"

Comment: There is no `DatePickerFragment` in Android. Do you really mean `DatePickerDialog`?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes. my bad. i updated the question. atm I am able to set the title using the `dialog.setTitle("something");` inside `Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, however, I am not able to change the title whenever I scroll either the date,month or year. Should I implement `onDateChange` Interface for that ?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I implement onDateChange Interface for that ?

That may work. I forget if `onDateChange()` is fired for every change, or only if the user accepts the dialog.

If it is only when the user accepts the dialog, then use `getDatePicker()` to get the `DatePicker` widget in the dialog, and register [an `OnDateChangedListener` with it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html), as that should be updated on every change.

Comment: where should I use the getDatePicker() ?

Comment: @tony9099: That is a method on `DatePickerDialog`.

Comment: @tony9099: A `DatePickerDialog` does not have a `TimePicker`.